# WebAPI using JSONP Error in callback

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I have a webapi that's using the JSONP nuget package, "WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp".

I have tried the Global.asax with the follow trhee declarations:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.AddJsonpFormatter();

var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.AddJsonpFormatter(config.Formatters.JsonForma‌​tter, "callback");
```

When I test the callback by dropping ?callback=Test at the end of the URL, it's returning the JSONP object, but it's adding some prefix:

```
/**/ typeof Test === 'function' &&
```

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by using ajax instead of getJSON.

```
function ajaxReq(url) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: url
    })
}
```